# How to add custom shipping fields in checkout and save them in database?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, custom-field

I need to add **some** **fields** to the **shipping address form** and save that **fields** into **database**.

Then show in **Billing Address** and **Shipping Address**. Please tell me how to do this thing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Follow this tutrial http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this example module to add a Extra Address Field to the Checkout.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFields

Comment: Hi Lewis, I tried this module but still no change only text field show in checkout page  and data not save in database.

Comment: yes, iam also facing the same problem

Comment: Yes, Also I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Download module from GitHub and make changes as per requirements.

[Magento2 Checkout Custom Form](https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form)